# Promises Angular2 ngOnInit this

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, es6-promise

I'm trying to assign a value from a promise into a variable (property). I can retrieve the value from the console.log. But when I'm trying to assign it to a "this" it won't work. see my code below:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    graphData:any;


    constructor(public _RelaticsService:RelaticsService, public _RelaticsDataTransformService:RelaticsDataTransformService) {


    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this._RelaticsService.GetData('persons', '37035202-abf8-4822-b8a5-b492c97a4c83', '123456')
            .then((val) =>
                this._RelaticsDataTransformService.ObjectTreeTransformation(val)
            )
            .then((val) => {
                console.log(val); // logs object
                this.graphData = val; // assigns object to this.graphdata
                console.log(this.graphData); // logs object
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log("rejected:", err));

        console.log(this.graphData) // logs undefined??

    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log(this.graphData) // logs undefined??
```

is executed before

```
this._RelaticsService.GetData('persons', '37035202-abf8-4822-b8a5-b492c97a4c83', '123456')
        .then((val) =>
            this._RelaticsDataTransformService.ObjectTreeTransformation(val)
        )
        .then((val) => {
            console.log(val); // logs object
            this.graphData = val; // assigns object to this.graphdata
            console.log(this.graphData); // logs object
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("rejected:", err));
```

This

```
this._RelaticsDataTransformService.ObjectTreeTransformation(val)
        )
        .then( /* passed code */ )
```

just schedules the passed code for later execution (when the call returns) and proceeds with execution of the following statments.

So your code seems to work fine, just the check is invalid.